# How can I center these divs to work correctly on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working from an HTML template to hone in on my HTML skills. I noticed that when the browser is small, all the sections anchor perfectly to the center of the display, except for one (the last one)

See screenshots:

Desktop (working perfectly)
[image: Desktop view]

But as soon as I resize to a mobile like view:
[image: Mobile view]

As you can see the first 2 are perfectly centred but the last one is anchored to the left.
I believe it has to do with the amount of text in section...
Meaning there is, in fact no centring by default in this template...

Here is my code

```
<div class="row mainFeatures" id="AboutUs">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/experience-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Experience</h4>
                    <p>Our experience in various industries benefits our clients when it comes to understanding their problem or requirements.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/quality-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Quality</h4>
                    <p>We believe in quality not quantity. We take the time to ensure our products and services are as reliable as possible.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/user-friendly-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>User-Friendly</h4>
                    <p>Most importantly, our products are easy to use and functional.<br /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have other CSS? There is no default centering in Bootstrap. You'd just use the `text-center` class in each col: http://www.codeply.com/go/fruF23dSys So there must be other CSS that's effecting the layout.

Comment: Nothing other than defaults, no...

Comment: If there was nothing else it would look like this: http://www.codeply.com/go/XejB08Hiht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-center` on each column: http://www.codeply.com/go/fruF23dSys

```
    <div class="row mainFeatures" id="AboutUs">
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/experience-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Experience</h4>
                    <p>Our experience in various industries benefits our clients when it comes to understanding their problem or requirements.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/quality-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Quality</h4>
                    <p>We believe in quality not quantity. We take the time to ensure our products and services are as reliable as possible.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/user-friendly-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>User-Friendly</h4>
                    <p>Most importantly, our products are easy to use and functional.
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note - there is no reason to use both `col-sm-4 col-md-4`. `col-sm-4` means 4 units on `sm` and up.

Answer (score 1):

you can use media queries to handle responsive design. you can learn more about media query [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) . but this should be helping you for current problem. 
give it an id or something and handle style for mobile size devices separately.

```
 @media (max-width:700px ) {
       #your_last_div{
            float: none;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add Bootstrap 'col-sm-4 col-xs-12' classes in your div

```
<div class="row mainFeatures" id="AboutUs">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img src="~/images/experience-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Experience</h4>
                <p>Our experience in various industries benefits our clients when it comes to understanding their problem or requirements.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img src="~/images/quality-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Quality</h4>
                <p>We believe in quality not quantity. We take the time to ensure our products and services are as reliable as possible.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img src="~/images/user-friendly-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>User-Friendly</h4>
                <p>Most importantly, our products are easy to use and functional.<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the reason for adding `col-sm-4 col-xs-12`? col-sm-4 is already there, and col-xs-12 is the default, meaning if it's excluded the columns with become full width on `xs` screens.

Comment: I have no idea why they are included in this way, these are the defaults provided in the template...

Comment: What do you mean "provided in the template"? Are you using *only* Bootstrap or is this HTML from a template/theme?

Answer (score 0):

(edited)

Try to add this CSS:

```
#AboutUs > div {
 text-align: center;
}
```

It centers each `.img-thumbnail` element inside its parent container, which is important when that container doesn't reach full width due to its content (by default they are aligned left, which you see only at the 3rd one, which has less content)

Answer (score 0):

use `text-center` class to align content center position, close the `img-thumbnail` div after image tag

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">


<div class="row mainFeatures" id="AboutUs">
  
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
<div class="img-thumbnail">
<img src="~/images/experience-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure"></div>
<div class="caption">
<h4>Experience</h4>
<p>Our experience in various industries benefits our clients when it comes to understanding their problem or requirements.</p>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
<div class="img-thumbnail">
<img src="~/images/quality-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
</div>
<div class="caption">
<h4>Quality</h4>
<p>We believe in quality not quantity. We take the time to ensure our products and services are as reliable as possible.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
<div class="img-thumbnail">
<img src="~/images/user-friendly-icon.png" width="85" height="88" alt="secure">
</div>
<div class="caption">
<h4>User-Friendly</h4>
<p>Most importantly, our products are easy to use and functional.<br /></p>
</div>
</div>
     
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is no extra closing DIV on the html code OP posted

Comment: there is a div closing mistake, close image-thumbnail div after img tag... updated my answer